# jquery, вставка проблела после точки или после запятой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, на сайте публикуются тексты, иногда пользователи не разделяют слова проблеми и получается следующее:
слово1,слово2,слово3,.... и т.д. Аналогично с точкой.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разделить такие строки пробелами, чтобы пробел ставился поле запятой или точки, но если он уже там есть то не ставился.

Comment: Либо регуляркой для более точного отлавливания, либо простейший вариант "string".split(',').join(', '), все равно дублирующий пробел браузер не выводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с использованием регулярного выражения:

```js
var sentence = 'word1,word2, word3.word4,word5';

sentence = sentence.replace(/(,|\.)(\S)/g, '$1 $2');

console.log(sentence); // word1, word2, word3. word4, word5
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно!